# Android Checkbox weird behavior (becomes disabled and clickable after bringing fragment from backstack)

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox, android-checkbox

I am currently facing an issue using CheckBox in my fragment.
Once the fragment is opened, the checkbox works properly.
The check box's behavior changes in two case:

- When I bring the fragment from the backStack using Back button
- When I open the fragment for the second time.

I t seems like when the fragment is reCreated, the checkBox becomes gray (disabled) and still clickable.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivLogo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideStart"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideEnd"/>
```

I tried to save its state but didn't work.

PS: After getting this behavior, (checkbox.isEnabled = true) doesn't work anymore.

Any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have such  behavior - so it's releated to your fragment code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !

I tried to override the theme of my Checkbox.
The only one that worked for me is: Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.CheckBox

The solution was to use a custom theme as following:

```
<style name="ABCheckBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceBodyMedium</item>
    <item name="buttonTint">@null</item>
</style>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ABCheckBox"
        android:checked="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Hope it would help you guys !

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd have to experiment with [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). Seems like you would need to remember a state and then use it to set the checkbox to a correct, previous state using for example `onResume()` or something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, even when I set checkbox.setEnable(true) in onResume method, it is not working. It stays always disabled when the fragment is recreated.

Comment: Something is probably overwriting that behaviour in your fragment then